# jquery fill dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var mddlrole = $('<%=ddlrole.ClientID %>');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ReportBasic.aspx/getroledata",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json;",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(response.d);
                    $(response.d.toString()).find('Table').each(function() {
                        var OptionValue = $(this).find('RoleID').text();
                        var OptionText = $(this).find('Name').text();
                        alert(OptionValue);
                        var option = $("<option>" + OptionText + "</option>");
                        option.attr("value", OptionValue);    
                        mddlrole.append(option);
                    });
                }

            });
        });
```

[image: response.d]
When I alert `response.d` I check if the data is successfully coming from server, but when I alert `OptionValue` it is coming as Blank.

Comment: Show what you get in `response.d` and learn to use `console.log()`

Comment: Please don't use alert() as a trouble-shooting device, use console.log() instead. http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/

Comment: i attach the response.d image.please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with xml, so you should change `contentType` to 'text/xml' from your ajax call and change xml managament callback to something like this

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( response.d.toString()),
$xml = $( xmlDoc )
$xml.find('Table').each(function() {
                var OptionValue = $(this).find('RoleID').text();
                var OptionText = $(this).find('Name').text();
                var option = new Option(OptionText,OptionValue);
                $(option).html(OptionText);
                mddlrole.append(option);

            });
```

Comment: Thanks i get the result in alert but when i bind it in dropdownlist it showing blank value.please help.

Comment: maybe your mddlrole selector is wrong. Maybe it should be var mddlrole = $('#<%=ddlrole.ClientID %>')?

Comment: Hello i was using that selected item value on cs page but it is giving me null value. 
int x = ddlrole.SelectedItem.Value;
it giving object refrence not set to instance of object error.